# How can I install brew httpd on MacOS 11 Big Sur?

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew

I've upgraded macOS version to 11 Big Sur and unable to use brew's apache instead of build in version.

What I did:

```
sudo apachectl stop
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null

brew intall httpd
```

When I'm trying to start the installed httpd it says that apache is started

```
==> Successfully started httpd (label: homebrew.mxcl.httpd)
```

but when I run `brew services` command I see that httpd is not started (and http://localhost:8080 is not working).

```
sergeylyskov@MacBook-Pro-Sergey ~ % brew services            
Name          Status  User         Plist
httpd         error   sergeylyskov /Users/sergeylyskov/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
php@7.3       stopped              
php@7.4       stopped              
postgresql@12 stopped
```

P.S. I want to use brew's version because seems like build in apache is not properly work with php modules (it don't show xdebug and imagick extensions in `phpinfo()`)

Any advice?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any luck solving it?

Comment: @WawaLoo unfortunately no progress on it, so I use docker now

Comment: I found that setting the ServerName in httpd.conf was causing this error. If you leave the ServerName commented, it just works. If you need virtualhosts and you want to use localhost, then you'll need to create a vhost for localhost as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried uninstalling and then reinstalling httpd, but that didn't work initially. When you uninstall, brew does NOT remove the `/usr/local/etc/httpd` config directory (which is sensible because you might have a lot of things configured in there and not backed up). However, these configuration files might well be outdated (or customized) in a way that makes them incompatible with the latest version of httpd, causing it to fail. So I did the following:

```
brew services stop httpd
brew uninstall httpd
mv /usr/local/etc/httpd /usr/local/etc/httpd-old
brew install httpd 
brew services start httpd
```

This got it running again with fresh config files; I can now copy over any specific configuration details from httpd-old into the new httpd dir.

Also note: by default, httpd serves from `/usr/local/var/www`. This dir is not affected by the uninstall-reinstall process, so only your config files need re-doing.

Comment: I did similar actions few days ago and yes, seems like old httpd files interfered with the normal installation of the new version

Comment: Are you sure you installed brew into /usr/local and not /opt/homebrew (/opt/homebrew is the default)?